# My code dont works but I don't know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code dont works but I don't know why

https://jsfiddle.net/byNickSan/p78pacvg/1/

jQuery 2.2.3

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: And now you expect us to guess what is working and what isn't? Please explain!

Comment: Change `data-target` to `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`. You are linking the wrong `id`.

Comment: "Dont works" is not a technical term. I voted to close this question because we don't have a clue about what "dont works".

Comment: please change your topic ,Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `data-target` to the correct element id. In your case `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` is the element id you want:

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
```